# Hiding a modal on clicking off in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button that turns on and off a connection. When the button is in on state and the user clicks on it. In order to turn it off, a modal pops up and asks for confirmation. But when the button is in off state, no modal should pop up. The problem is that its the same button that is being toggled to display "On" and "Off" and a modal element is attached to it. Even when the off button is clicked the modal pops up which I don't want. Please help me out.

```
if(status == 'On'){                      
      var url = "/streams/status";
      $('button[id="modal-'+ streamId + '"]').click(function(){
        console.log("close modal function")
        $('myModal-'+ streamId).modal('hide');
        $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: url,
         data: "streamId="+streamId,
         success: function(res){
          $('button[id="profile-'+ res.streamId + '"]').toggleClass('btn-success btn-danger');
          $('button[id="profile-'+ res.streamId + '"]').text(function (){
            console.log($(this).text())
            return 'Off';
            }); 
         },
         error: function (res){
          console.log('there was an error', res);
         }
      });
    })
  }
  else{

    console.log("button is off currently"); 
    $('myModal-' + streamId).modal('hide');
    var url = "/streams/status";
    $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: url,
     data: "streamId="+streamId,
     success: function(res){
      $('button[id="profile-'+ res.streamId + '"]').toggleClass('btn-success btn-danger');
      $('button[id="profile-'+ res.streamId + '"]').text(function (){
        console.log($(this).text())
        return 'On';

        }); 
     },
     error: function (res){
      console.log('there was an error', res);
     }
   });

  }
  })
```

Comment: you cannot return value from success callback, ajax is async. BTW, i don't think you need to return any value at all, just use `status = !status` and set status as boolean

Comment: Shows as part of your html page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct way to do it:

```
    script.
      function toggleStatus (streamId, statusBefore){
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:  "/streams/status",
    data: "streamId="+streamId,
    success: function(res){
      $('button[id="profile-'+ res.streamId + '"]')
        .toggleClass('btn-success btn-danger')
        .attr('data-toggle', statusBefore == true ? "": 'modal');
      $('#profile-glyphicon-'+ res.streamId).toggleClass('glyphicon-ok glyphicon-remove');
    },
    error: function (res){
      console.log('there was an error', res);
    }
  });
}
$('button[id^="modal-"]').click(function(){
  var streamId = this.id.split('-')[1];
  toggleStatus(streamId, true);
  $('myModal-'+streamId).modal('hide');
})
$('button[id^="profile-"]').on("click", function(e){
  var streamId = this.id.split('-')[1];
  var statusBefore;
  var dataToggleStatus = $('#profile-' + streamId).attr("data-toggle");
  if(dataToggleStatus=='modal'){
    statusBefore = true;
    e.preventDefault();
  } else  {
    statusBefore = false;
    toggleStatus(streamId, statusBefore);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should add a rel attribute (off or on), detect onclick event and check this attribute :

```
$('#myModal-' + streamId).click(function(event){

  if($('#myModal-' + streamId).attr('rel') == 'on'){
    //do ajax request ON here
    //on success ajax, replace return 'off' by 
    $('#myModal-' + streamId).attr('rel', 'off');
  }
  else{
    //do ajax request OFF here
    //on success ajax, replace return 'on' by 
    $('#myModal-' + streamId).attr('rel', 'on');
  }
}
```

it should be works